# get specific tagName from a var js

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

I have a var saved my encoded data

```
console.log(encodedData)
```

it's look like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="185" height="104">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M 184 64 c -0.14 -0.09 -5.24 -3.95 -8 -5 c -3.9 -1.49 -8.71 -2.82 -13 -3 c -11.25 -0.47 -23.46 -0.3 -35 1 c -12.09 1.36 -23.69 4.22 -36 7 c -16.61 3.76 -31.5 8.08 -48 12 c -3.73 0.88 -7.32 1.74 -11 2 c -5.6 0.4 -11.48 0.42 -17 0 c -2.99 -0.23 -6.16 -1.13 -9 -2 c -1.38 -0.42 -3.12 -1.12 -4 -2 c -0.88 -0.88 -1.91 -2.71 -2 -4 c -0.21 -3.18 0.11 -7.78 1 -11 c 0.65 -2.35 2.39 -4.86 4 -7 c 5.38 -7.18 10.67 -15.3 17 -21 c 6.43 -5.79 15.06 -10.4 23 -15 c 4.79 -2.77 9.82 -4.93 15 -7 c 4.95 -1.98 9.9 -3.63 15 -5 c 3.61 -0.97 7.23 -1.49 11 -2 c 3.72 -0.51 7.45 -1.24 11 -1 c 6.19 0.41 12.92 1.53 19 3 c 3.4 0.82 7.06 2.19 10 4 c 5.46 3.36 11.88 7.42 16 12 c 4.34 4.83 8.34 11.74 11 18 c 3.83 9.01 6.88 19.15 9 29 c 2.54 11.79 5 36 5 36"/>
</svg>
```

how can I get just the svg Tag from it ?

Comment: please post code sample, what you have tried so far

Comment: Try `var test = document.createElement('div'); test.innerHTML = encodedData; test = test.querySelector('svg')`.

Comment: Is `encodedData` a string or a `Document`? If the former, have you tried parsing it into a `Document`? If the latter, have you tried selecting the `svg` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy element and assign your variable to it.

```
var elem = document.createElement( 'html' );
elem.innerHTML = encodedData;
console.log(elem.getElementsByTagName( 'svg' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `encodedData` holds a string, [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) it into a `Document`:

```js
const svgDOM = new DOMParser().parseFromString(encodedData, "image/svg+xml");
```

If it’s already a `Document`, [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) the `svg` element:

```js
const svgElem = svgDOM.querySelector("svg"); // or `encodedData.querySelector("svg")`
```

If you need the `<svg>` tag as a string, [serialize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) it back into a string:

```js
const svgTag = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElem, "image/svg+xml");
```